# Interior points of $A= \{(x,y): y=0 \}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Find the interior points of $A= \{(x,y): y=0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I am working through some examples in preparation for an exam and I was fine with every example except the one given above. Can anyone please show me how to find the interior points of the given set?

Comment: Does $A$ contain *any* non-empty open ball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interior is empty, as there is no point in $A$ for which there is an open neighborhood that is also contained in $A$.